# NPOI Bar/Column Chart?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, npoi

I need to create a simple bar chart on excel and export it.
After searching examples on NPOI's repo and through code, I saw that is just possible to create line and scatter chart.

I'm considering to create a excel template with chart already created and so modify their axis.

What I need is just a confirmation that is not possible to create a bar/column chart with NPOI.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking into NPOI github issues I found that is possible. But it has some limitations.

I can't set decimals on chart, but after some investigations on Java thread about data format, I was able to resolve just changing the current thread culture.

Below the code example:

```
private void CreateChart(int columnQtt, int rowIndex, int tipoId, string currentTipo, ISheet sheet, int startDataRow)
{
    XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = (XSSFClientAnchor)drawing.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, columnQtt + 1, startDataRow - 2, columnQtt + 10, startDataRow + 12);
    XSSFChart chart = (XSSFChart)drawing.CreateChart(anchor);

    IBarChartData<string, double> barChartData = chart.ChartDataFactory.CreateBarChartData<string, double>();
    IChartLegend legend = chart.GetOrCreateLegend();
    legend.Position = LegendPosition.Bottom;

    IChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom);
    bottomAxis.MajorTickMark = AxisTickMark.None;
    IValueAxis leftAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateValueAxis(AxisPosition.Left);
    leftAxis.Crosses = AxisCrosses.AutoZero;
    leftAxis.SetCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.Between);

    int endDataRow = rowIndex - 1;

    IChartDataSource<string> categoryAxis = DataSources.FromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(startDataRow, endDataRow, 0, 0));
    IChartDataSource<double> valueAxis = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(startDataRow, endDataRow, columnQtt - 1, columnQtt - 1));
    var serie = barChartData.AddSeries(categoryAxis, valueAxis);
    serie.SetTitle(currentTipo);    

    chart.Plot(barChartData, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
}
```